# Decouple a single address string to city, country etc separately

Tags: c#, extract, street-address

I am writing a program which take a string of address and break it down into city, country etc. Let say someone speak New York City U.S. or U.S. New York after decoupled they both be country = U.S. and city = New York City.

Comment: Will the address string always be in a consistent format?  Show us some sample data.

Comment: No, coz it's from speech to text. Let say "what is the weather like UK London or London UK". Really depend on the person who have spoken.

Comment: You should provide a code example of what you have tried.This isn't how this website works.

Comment: @LittleFunny try to experiment with google API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Answer (score 0):

You'd need

- A special format for cities / countries to identify them
- Or a database (Or some lists with the data) to compare the different solutions, which develop by using other values from the city than the intended city, wether they suite the data.

There sadly is no magic method which returns you the string splitted into country and city.